# Is is possible to reduce this logic diagram?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to reduce the 'full subtractor' to less than 7 total logic gates?

Here I'm counting 'one' logic gate to be one of the `AND, OR, XOR, NOT, NAND, NOR or XNOR` gates.

[image: enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way one normally handles subtraction is to negate the second term, that is you basically adds $A$ and $-B$, except that negation is hardish so one uses inversion instead that is arithmetically $-1-B$. So you add $A$, $-1-B$ and $1$ (which the later is injected as carry to the LSB).

Then you will just need a [full adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Full_adder) instead. Adjusted for the fact that we invert $B$ the expression (for bit $j$) would be:

$$S_j = A_j\oplus \overline B_j \oplus C_{j-1}$$
$$C_j = A_j\overline B_j + C_{j-1}(A_j\oplus \overline B_j)$$

Which with reuse of subexpression would be one NOT (generating $\overline B_j$), two XORs (generating $A_j\oplus\overline B_j$ and $(A_j\oplus\overline B_j)\oplus C_{j-1}$), two ANDs (generating $A_j\overline B_j$ and $C_{j-1}(A_j\oplus\overline B_j)$) and one OR (generating $(A_j\overline B_j)+(C_{j-1}(A_j\oplus \overline B_j))$) per bit, that is one gate less than yours. The carry in $C_{j-1}$ is the output carry for the next lower bit (for bit $0$ we would hard wire $C_{-1}=1$ to generate the $+1$ as mentioned before).

Comment: I have a bit of a hard time following this, sorry. Are you saying that the circuit in as provided by the OP is incorrect?  And if so, is the table you have at the beginning of your post the table of that circuit, or the table of how things should actually work?

Also, at the end you have $C=A\overline{B}+C(A\oplus \overline{B})$. So $C$ is a function of $C$? And is this $C$ supposed to be the Borrow bit or the Difference bit? And which one is $S$?

And at the very end, how do you end up with one NOT, two XORs, two ANDs, and one OR?

Comment: @Bram28 Something were definitely wrong and something were unclear. I hope I've improved the answer - the table is that for the OP's circuit (except the value of $A-B-C$ which is what $A-B-C$ actually is). The equation didn't distinguish between carry in and carry out. Also I've indicated which expressions the various gates are generating - I don't think I have any good SW for producing a circuit scheme.

Comment: OK, thanks, that helps!  BUt one more question: if the table is for the OP's circuit, and you say that it seems 'broken' ... is that then not the table we want? BUt it seems intuitively right to me: borrow is 1 when A-B-C is negative, and the Difference is 1 when ther are an odd number of 1s on the input ... is that not correct?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, it's probably correct after all so I removed that part.

Comment: Ah!  And I see now how you used the term $A_j \oplus \overline{B}$ twice to cut down on operators, and how it becomes 6 total. ... brain freeze on my part :)  OK, but one last thing though: isn't the $S_j$ supposed to be the 'answer output bit', and the $C_j$ the bit indicating the Borrow?  But then, don't we want the 'answer bit' to be $1$ iff there are an odd number of $1$s, and thus be $A \oplus B \oplus C$?  I feel the answer is in that you change from a subtractor to an adder, but in the end aren't we looking for a circuit with $Difference$ and $Borrow$ a function of A,B,and C?

Comment: +1 by the way ... thanks for helping me think through this!

Comment: @Bram28 Yes $S_j$ is the answer bit. The confusing part is that we're using an adder to subtract so $C_j$ is actually the carry. We're adding $A$ the bitwise inverse of $B$ (which is $-1-B$) and $1$ (which we get by injecting a carry bit for the LSB). If you want to think of it in terms of borrow the $C_j$ bit is the inverse of borrow.